# python3 - how to create tar and zip file. getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x

**python3 - how to create tar and zip file**

```
prevdir = os.getcwd()    
os.chdir('/tmp/')
print("Compressing files to %s..." % FILE)
with tarfile.open(FILE, "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add(build_path)
os.chdir(prevdir)
```

**getting following error**:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File "./tar_n_upload.py", line 74, in <module>
>     main(sys.argv[1:])   
> File "./tar_n_upload_vcs.py", line 69, in main
>     with tarfile.open(FILE, "w:gz") as tar: 
> AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute '__exit__'
> ```

I don't know what I am missing anything here.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This error would be expected in Python 3.1 and 2.6, because `TarFile` objects weren't context managers yet, but it should work in 3.2+ and 2.7.

Comment: I am using Python 3.1.1. Let me check on the other versions as you suggested. thank you

Comment: Well, that’s your problem. You’re trying to use a feature that was added in 3.2 with 3.1, so it fails. It’s not that hard to work around this with `contextlib.closing`, or just a manual `close`call. But first: why are you using 3.1 in the first place?  That’s an ancient version, and one that almost nobody used except for the kind of early adopters who switched to 3.2 the day the first beta came out.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you just stick to 3.1 for some reason, you’ll have to be careful to read docs, samples, etc. for 3.1, not the current version, or at least look carefully for the “Added in:” line in the later docs.

Comment: I tried the latest python and the same work perfectly fine. Thanks very much !